# How to filter to output of the get_permalink() function

Tags: permalinks, filters

I know how to filter the output of the function `the_permalink` - it is like this:

```
add_filter('the_permalink', 'my_the_permalink');
function my_the_permalink($url) {
    return 'http://mysite/my-link/';
}
```

And it works when I use it like: `<?PHP the_permalink($id); ?>`, but I wanted to change the link returned by `get_permalink($id)` function. And this filter doesn't affect the returned permalink in that case.

I was trying to catch it with:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'my_get_permalink', 10, 3);
function my_get_permalink($url, $post, $leavename=false) {
    return 'http://mysite/my-link/';
}
```

But this filter isn't fired for the `get_permalink()`. So how can I alter the links returned by the `get_permalink()`?

Comment: I know I can define a function like `get_my_permalink()` and use it instead of `get_permalink()` but I am wondering if I can do this on some higher level.

Comment: ^ That solution works great, it just makes a PHP warning: PHP Warning: Missing argument 3 for {closure} ()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that `post_link` filter is only for the `post` post type.

For other *post types* these filters are available:

- [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) for *custom post types*
- [`page_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_link/) for *page*
- [`attachment_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_link/) for *attachment*

The `get_permalink()`function is actually a wrapper for:

- `get_post_permalink()`
- `get_attachement_link()`
- `get_page_link()`

in those cases.

Here's a way (untested) to create a custom `wpse_link` filter for all the above cases of `get_permalink()`:

```
foreach( [ 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'post_type' ] as $type )
{
    add_filter( $type . '_link', function ( $url, $post_id, ? bool $sample = null ) use ( $type )
    {
        return apply_filters( 'wpse_link', $url, $post_id, $sample, $type );
    }, 9999, 3 );
}
```

where we can now filter all cases with:

```
add_filter( 'wpse_link', function(  $url, $post_id, $sample, $type )
{
    return $url;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: I'm testing it on a regular post `add_filter('post_type_link',...` doesn't affect `get_permalink()` for me neither. I think I will just write my own function like `get_my_permalink()` to wrapping the `get_permalink()` to solve this "problem" fast and easy.

Comment: Strange, does the same happen on a vanilla install? and you're sure (sorry for asking this) the `$id` in `get_permalink( $id )` is for the *post* post type? @Picard

Comment: I should've been more specific - it is `page` type, and `page_link` works with it fine. I expected some filter for all post types like `add_filter('get_permalink', ...`, but since there isn't your answer is fine, thanks.

Comment: ok, i updated the answer with an untested workaround @Picard

Comment: Thanks, just add `{` when `foreach` opens, besides that works great - allows to override links for both `get_permalink()` and `the_permalink` for page type posts - I will do tests for other post types later.

Comment: Here's the full list of link filters:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Link_Filters

Comment: My media library broke with this. Saying too few arguments. To fix, on line 3 add a default value for sample, `$sample = null`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, please feel free to update answer as needed.  @Davey

Comment: I made an edit - I *think* it will be widely compatible with php and WP vesrions but  it's only tested on my one instance.

Comment: awesome thanks @Davey

Answer (score 1):

I successfully use this statement.

```php
add_filter('post_type_link', function ($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
  if ($post->post_type == 'mycustomposttype') {
    ...
    $post_link = 'https://my.custom.site' . $some_uri;
  }
  return $post_link;
}, 999, 4);
```